# Spring Authorization Server and Spring Resource Server in one server

Tags: spring-security

Has anyone tried using both the newly release Spring Authorization Server 0.1.0 and the regular Spring Resource Server in 1 project and in 1 server such as:

The resource server is at http://localhost:8080 and the authorization server is also at http://localhost:8080? Any ideas on how to do it?

The problem is that at start up, the resource server checks the authorization server's `/.well-known/openid-configuration` which is obviously not yet avaialble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `issuer-uri`, you can instead specify the `jwk-set-uri`, which isn't pinged at startup.

Or, since the authorization server and resource server will use the memory space for keys, you might construct your own Nimbus `JWTProcessor` instead so that you skip the internal HTTP request:

```java
@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> source = // ... some internal store for the public keys, e.g. not RemoteJWKSet
    ConfigurableJWTProcessor<SecurityContext> processor = new DefaultJWTProcessor<>();
    JWSKeySelector<SecurityContext> selector = new JWSVerificationKeySelector(
        JWSAlgorithm.RS256, source);
    processor.setJWSKeySelector(selector);
    NimbusJwtDecoder decoder = new NimbusJwtDecoder(processor);
    decoder.setJwtValidator(... add any validation rules ...);
    return decoder;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a great idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just set your jwtDecoder as follows:

```
@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
    return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
}
```

As you probably already have that defined as a Bean elsewhere when setting up your auth server

```
@Bean
public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
    // implementation ...
}
```